# Connecting chrome extension to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

I am planning to develop a chrome extension, which adds/appends data to my Google spreadsheet. There are multiple choices on net and I am a beginner and don't know the exact route to achieve the same. Also I am new to JavaScript which makes it difficult for me to understand the contents of a resource on the internet. Please suggest some good links and resources and it would be even better if I can get some sample.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/ can help you learn Javascript. You'll need a solid foundation in JS to develope a Chrome extension and Google Sheets add-on (depending on what you want to do, you may need to do both).

Answer (score 1):

One easy aproach would be to make a Chrome Extension that does calls to an apps script WebApp, with [apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started) you can interact with spreadsheets in an easy way, deploying [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with apps script it's not that difficult. 
So a chrome extension could just call a WebApp in order to do the desired stuff on spreadsheet.

A second approach, maybe easier, is to develop an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/install-editor-addons) with apps script, add-ons run on the spreadsheet side, not on the Browser.

So it's not a chrome extension, but I believe this approach may eventually be enough for your purposes and it may shorten the path to make possible whatever you are attempting to.

---

Simplest web App example:

- Go to script.google.com
- Paste this:

```js
function doGet(){
    var appData = {
      "title": "WebApp JSON example",
      "content": "Welcome to this example"
    };
    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(appData);
    var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
    JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return JSONOutput
}
```

- Click on Publish --> Deploy as WebApp
- Get the link and paste it to your browser

As you can see, by entering on this link you'll execute what it is inside doGet() function on apps script.

So, you could call a webapp like this one on your Chrome extension and get whatever you need to be done on your spreadsheet in an easy way.

Comment: Hello Yuri, I followed what you said, and it looks like the first approach would be feasible for me. 

Following your advice and the tutorial, I went to the spreadsheet and created a small function, and then I deployed it as a Web App. When I run this script directly from the script editor, I am able to append a row to the sheet. But I want to pass data to this function from my extension so that it gets appended to the sheet. For that, I need to call this WebApp.

**Can you please suggest some tutorial where can call the Web App with the JS file in my extension.** Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I pasted the link from the above script, I got the following error:-
`TypeError: Cannot call method "toUpperCase" of undefined. (line 5, file "Code", project "test")`. 

I am very thankful to you for your help, but I am still unable to figure out, how to call this webapp from my extension. Please help.

Comment: This error is not related with the code pasted, because that code does not have 'toUpperCase' function at all. I suggest you start from the begging playing with apps script.

Comment: I created a web script and deployed it as a web app and used the link generated for calling it through my extension. Here it is:
`function onclick3 () {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
      var url = tabs[0].url;
      var url3 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/1231231sdfsfd/exec";      
      var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      x.open('POST',url3);
      x.send();
    })
  }`

But the web app script is not being executed. Am I sending the request wrong way? Are there any prerequisites that I may be missing?

Answer (score -1):

[Javascript Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) is a good place to learn JS and many other languages.

[How To Create A Google Chrome Extension: A Step-by-Step Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh84Asy2W4s) is a short 8 min video easy to understand.

With these 2 references, I was able to build my first extension that we use in our office everyday.

Comment: Thanks, Jason, but isn't it possible that I can somehow get a hint of how to connect the chrome extension to spreadsheets

Comment: Well yes, but you asked for "Please suggest some good links and resources and it would be even better if I can get some sample".  what I provided was the resources I used to learn how to build my script, but if you want a hint from me on how to connect the chrome extension to the spreadsheets, look to my 2nd answer.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're wanting to take the easier way out and I can assure you, it's much more refreshing to learn this stuff and only come here to ask the technical questions.  People out here are willing to help, but trust me, they like to see you put the effort.  If not, your question can be flagged for not attempting to research.  Try those links out and you'll learn a lot and what you're trying to do, you will be able to do with ease.

Comment: I created a web script and deployed it as a web app and used the link generated for calling it through my extension. Here it is:
`function onclick3 () {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
      var url = tabs[0].url;
      var url3 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/1231231sdfsfd/exec";      
      var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      x.open('POST',url3);
      x.send();
    })
  }`

But the web app script is not being executed. Am I sending the request wrong way? Are there any prerequisites that I may be missing?

Comment: I'm not very onto chrome extension, you should try to make request to other resources to see if the problem is within the web app or it's on your call.

Comment: You should test your script in the console.  Verify it works there before accessing it in the extension.  There you should get the errors to research your issues.